# Pointer to string with spaces

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, int

Given a pointer and a variable containing the size of this pointer.

What I have to do to create an array of char containing the hexadecimal value of each byte followed by a space.

input:

```
char *pointer = "test"; 
int size = 5;
```

output:

```
"74 65 73 74 00"
```

The pointer is not necessarily a string, could be to any address.

I can print it, but do not know how to save in a variable.

```
char *buffer = "test";
unsigned int size = 5;
unsigned int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("%x ", buffer[i]);
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the output statement you are using (very important)?

Comment: i need an string/array of char with that output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Since you are using C++, look up the `hex` I/O Manipulator:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags

If you want to use the C style I/O, look up the `printf` modifier, `%x`, as in `"0x%02X "`.

**Edit 1:**
To save in a variable, using C style functions:

```
char hex_buffer[256];
unsigned int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    snprintf(hex_buffer, sizeof(hex_buffer),
             "%x ", buffer[i]);
}
```

Using C++, lookup the `std::ostringstream`:

```
  std::ostring stream;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    stream << hex << buffer[i] << " ";
  }
  std::string my_hex_text = stream.str();
```

Comment: i know how to print, i need save in a variable

Comment: In your next post, please clarify.

Comment: 2nd hint: look up ostringstream.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *f(const char *buff, unsigned size){
    char *result = malloc(2*size + size-1 +1);//element, space, NUL
    char *p = result;
    unsigned i;

    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        if(i)
            *p++ = ' ';
        sprintf(p, "%02x", (unsigned)buff[i]);
        p+=2;
    }
    return result;
}
int main(void){
    char *buffer = "test";
    unsigned int size = 5;
    char *v = f(buffer, size);
    puts(v);
    free(v);
    return 0;
}
```